# draw polygon on canvas with mouse events

Tags: javascript, canvas

I want to let user to draw polygon shape on canvas same as the tool in paint.Below is my code.
The problem is it works fine when user drags first line and simply clicks afterwards to complete the shape however when the user drags next line before completing the polygon the logic fails.Can anyone please correct my code.

```
  var startPointX = "", startPointY = "", endpointX, endpointY, isnewShape = false;
tools.polygon = function () {
    var tool = this;
    this.started = false;

    this.mousedown = function (ev) {
        tool.started = true;
        tool.x0 = ev._x;
        tool.y0 = ev._y;

        if ((Math.abs(startPointX - ev._x) < 5) && (Math.abs(startPointY - ev._y) < 5) && (startPointX != ev._x && startPointY != ev._y) && !isnewShape) {
            alert('point matched');
            startPointX = "";
            startPointY = "";
            isnewShape = true;
            context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

            context.beginPath();
            context.moveTo(endpointX, endpointY);

            context.lineTo(ev._x, ev._y);
            endpointX = ev._x;
            endpointY = ev._y;
            context.stroke();
            context.closePath();
            img_update();
            tool.started = false;
        }
        else {
            //                console.log(isnewShape);

            if (startPointX == "" || startPointY == "")
                return;

            context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

            context.beginPath();
            context.moveTo(endpointX, endpointY);
            isnewShape = false;
            context.lineTo(ev._x, ev._y);
            endpointX = ev._x;
            endpointY = ev._y;
            context.stroke();
            context.closePath();
            img_update();
        }

    };

    this.mousemove = function (ev) {
        if (!tool.started) {
            return;
        }
        // console.log('mousemove');
        context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

        context.beginPath();
        context.lineTo(ev._x, ev._y);
        endpointX = ev._x;
        endpointY = ev._y;
        context.stroke();
        context.closePath();
    };

    this.mouseup = function (ev) {
        if (tool.started) {

            if (startPointX == "" && startPointY == "") {

                startPointX = tool.x0;
                startPointY = tool.y0;

            }

            tool.started = false;
            img_update();
        }
    };
};

function init() {
    // Find the canvas element.
    canvaso = document.getElementById('imageView');
    if (!canvaso) {
        alert('Error: I cannot find the canvas element!');
        return;
    }

    if (!canvaso.getContext) {
        alert('Error: no canvas.getContext!');
        return;
    }

    // Get the 2D canvas context.
    contexto = canvaso.getContext('2d');
    if (!contexto) {
        alert('Error: failed to getContext!');
        return;
    }

    // Add the temporary canvas.
    var container = canvaso.parentNode;
    canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    if (!canvas) {
        alert('Error: I cannot create a new canvas element!');
        return;
    }

    canvas.id = 'imageTemp';
    canvas.width = canvaso.width;
    canvas.height = canvaso.height;
    container.appendChild(canvas);

    context = canvas.getContext('2d');

    // Get the tool select input.
    var tool_select = document.getElementById('dtool');
    if (!tool_select) {
        alert('Error: failed to get the dtool element!');
        return;
    }
    tool_select.addEventListener('change', ev_tool_change, false);

    // Activate the default tool.
    if (tools[tool_default]) {
        tool = new tools[tool_default]();
        tool_select.value = tool_default;
    }

    // Attach the mousedown, mousemove and mouseup event listeners.
    canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', ev_canvas, false);
    canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', ev_canvas, false);
    canvas.addEventListener('mouseup', ev_canvas, false);
}

// The general-purpose event handler. This function just determines the mouse 
// position relative to the canvas element.
function ev_canvas(ev) {
    if (ev.layerX || ev.layerX == 0) { // Firefox
        ev._x = ev.layerX;
        ev._y = ev.layerY;
    } else if (ev.offsetX || ev.offsetX == 0) { // Opera
        ev._x = ev.offsetX;
        ev._y = ev.offsetY;
    }

    // Call the event handler of the tool.
    var func = tool[ev.type];
    if (func) {
        func(ev);
    }
}

// The event handler for any changes made to the tool selector.
function ev_tool_change(ev) {
    if (tools[this.value]) {
        tool = new tools[this.value]();
    }
}

// This function draws the #imageTemp canvas on top of #imageView, after which 
// #imageTemp is cleared. This function is called each time when the user 
// completes a drawing operation.
function img_update() {
    contexto.drawImage(canvas, 0, 0);
    context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
}
```

Comment: A fiddle would be easier.

Comment: What's you `img_update()` do can you please put your full code into jsfiddle.

Comment: @SumanBogati i don't really know how jsfiddle works, i have updated my code with all functions.Please check.Thanks in advance.

Comment: The importance of the fiddle is that we can see a fairly complete (if misbehaving) code base.  For example, I put your code in an empty html shell, added an imageView canvas, added a dtool div(?) and now I get an error that `tools` is undefined.  So you're making us work and guess to even get to a starting point for fixing your problem.